# In-app Consumable Purchases with Urbanairship

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, urbanairship.com

I am working on this app where you can buy consumable items. The in-app purchases are set as consumable on itunes and I'm using urbairship. The PROBLEM is that when I'm buying an item it only asks once (the first time) to pay for it. After that, it works the same but no AlertView show's to ask you to pay for it. It enters the delegate as if you had payed for the product.

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

UPDATE:

```
[UAStoreFront registerObserver: self];
//[[UAStoreFront shared] setDelegate:self];

// Urban Airship Subscriptions
[UAStoreFront useCustomUI:[UAStoreFrontUI class]];

// Init Airship launch options
NSMutableDictionary *takeOffOptions = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];
[takeOffOptions setValue:[[AppDelegate appDelegate] appDelegateLaunchOptions] forKey:      UAirshipTakeOffOptionsLaunchOptionsKey];

// Create Airship singleton that's used to talk to Urban Airship servers.
// Please populate AirshipConfig.plist with your info from http://go.urbanairship.com
[UAirship takeOff:takeOffOptions];

[UAStoreFront registerObserver: self];
[[UAStoreFront shared] setDelegate:self];
[UAStoreFront resetAndLoadInventory];
```

this code is in viewDidLoad.

And i have a method that makes the request:

```
- (IBAction)pushBuyMoreTime
{
   [UAStoreFront purchase: @"in-app id"];
}
```

And it calls this delegate even if it didn't ask me to pay:

```
-(void)productPurchased:(UAProduct*) product {
}
```

Comment: How you did it with UrbanAirShip ? Can you post some code or link for this which helped in setting up the whole environment.